# Express JS: serving files out of memory vs serving static files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is it worth my while to hold images(for example) in memory, as opposed to serving them out of static assets?

Will frequently requested static assets remain in memory?

Can anyone give me a sense of the performance impact?

Comment: I have done quick benchmarks and the results are: for an image 685KB, an average server response time is 1-2ms when served from cache and 10-15ms when server from an SSD. Thats approx. 650MB of memory for 1000 images. Considering the price difference between an SSD and memory storage, it is hardly worth it. Your time and money will be better spent investing in a good CDN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're serving users in the several thousands per second, I doubt it'll have that much of an impact since the bottleneck is bound to be network latency and transfer times anyway.

Regardless, you should utilize client-side cache in your favor, and make sure that the image isn't requested from the server each time.

Frequently requested images are not kept in memory by default as far as I know, you need to write your own application level code to do that.

The best advice I can give you is to try both and see what works *for you*. Your conditions and circumstances are unique to you, and no benchmark can give you an accurate representation of whether it's worth the extra memory usage or not.

Comment: What about server CPU time? Probably negligible differences?